# How to check whether an input field was left empty in Maxima?

Tags: stack, maxima

I am creating linear algebra problems in Stack. The integrated computer algebra system that's used by Stack is Maxima.

To perform certain checks on the students' answers I need to know whether an input field was completed by the student at all or not. I can refer to the answers of the students by their names *ans1*, *ans2*, *ans3*,... . How can I check in Maxima whether for ex. the variable *ans1* is empty or null or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `?boundp` or `member(..., values)`:

```
(%i1) x: 42$
(%i2) ?boundp('x);
(%o2)                                true
(%i3) ?boundp('y);
(%o3)                                false
(%i4) member('x, values);
(%o4)                                true
(%i5) member('y, values);    
(%o5)                                false
```